# How to retrieve the data returned by an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, http-post

I make an AJAX post request to get processed data from DB in form of "array" [value1, value2, value3,...,valueN] to later use it on a chartJS object.

AJAX Request:

```
$(document).ready($.post('callMeForAJAX.jsp', function(data){
    values = data;
    console.log(data);
}));
```

But it doesn't print anything on the console even though I can see the response on the "Network" tab on the Development Tools from Chrome.

How can I retrieve that data (isn't more than a String) to put it on the "data" parameter of the Chart object?

callMeForAJAX.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%

  String data = "[";
  for(String s : InfoFacade.getData()){
      data += s+", ";
  }
  data += "]";
  response.getWriter().write(data);

%>
```

Edit: If relevant, I was using 1.2.x jQuery lib and now I have upgraded to 2.x without any changes.

Comment: JavaScript noob over here. Be gentle :)

Comment: `$(document).ready($.post()....);` is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/yourUrl",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {

                        $("#yourIdContainerToShowResult").html(result);


                }
            });
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: Your solution seems to work as expected. Can you please correct my approach by saying what was wrong with the way I was trying to do things?

Also: How can I store that data on a variable that is outside the AJAX request? It is undefined once I try to print it outside the callback.

Comment: @AndrésBuitrago 1. instead of $.post() you may use $.ajax()

Comment: Yeah, I get that. According to jQuery docs that's just a shorter way to do it so I decided to use that way. On the other hand, can you help me with the second miniquestion about how to save that data on a global variable? Here's a jsfiddle so you can understand what I'm trying to do https://jsfiddle.net/zsjjcmjL/. 

It keeps saying values is undefined.

Comment: @AndrésBuitrago I looked to your code so, with that way you posting data as NULL  as that you are getting values as undefined , first of all you must serialize your data as like this: var data =  $("#yourOrderFormId").serialize();   if it helps pls, mark up my solution ;)

Comment: This code ' $(document).ready(ajaxCall()) '  must be like this $(document).ready(function(){ ajaxCall(); });

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(document).ready()` block is not correct.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('callMeForAJAX.jsp', function(data){
        values = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. I must use an anon function there.

But, still, there's nothing showing up in console.

Comment: It is. I get the correct response but it won't do anything in the function.

Comment: What is `values`? If it is not defined then you might getting problem because of this.

Comment: It is a js variable outside the AJAX request.

var values;
(AJAX REQUEST HERE)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

$(function(){

callMeForAJAX();

});

```
function callMeForAJAX(){
$.post( "callMeForAJAX.jsp", function(data){
 if(data.length > 0)
 console.log(data);
 else
 console.log("DATA NULL");  
});
}
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything on the console.

Comment: Check  if(data.length >0)

Comment: It doesn't print any of the messages.